Columns to Rows in Vertica
I have a query that outputs an A/B test planning. in simplicity, it has several columns of interest and rows that specify the length of the test.
Up untill now i have used "UNION ALL" to switch the columns to rows(the original code had the  columns as rows and i switched it).
Now i added 3 more KPI's to calculate and I get a memory allocation problem. i dont have the option to increase my memory alocation atm, is there a more efficient way to switch columns into rows without union all in vertica?
thank you
P.S
ofcourse I have tried asking GPT but not much luck..

You might be wanting to do something like this:
Out of this ....



Shift
day01
day02
day03
day04




D
133
123
16
124


N
12
3
15
4


X
2
4
5
6



Make this:



shift
day_i
val




D
1
133


D
2
123


D
3
16


D
4
124


N
1
12


N
2
3


N
3
15


N
4
4


X
1
2


X
2
4


X
3
5


X
4
6



I usually call 'unpivoting' the operation of verticalising columns into rows, and 'pivoting' the reverse operation - aggregate several rows into one by horizontalising one or more measures. I know there are 'schools' that define this stuff exactly the other way around. Maybe I should use 'pivot horizontally' and 'pivot vertically' to avoid confusion ...
The trick is to explode your rows by CROSS JOINing them with a series of consecutive integers (my i correlation in the query below, and use the i  index in a CASE WHEN expression to pick the right previously horizontally depicted value for the current row. And just to showcase Vertica's peculiarities, I use Vertica's TIMESERIES clause to create a bunch of rows out of (almost) nothing:
WITH
-- some input data ...
input(Shift,day01,day02,day03,day04) AS (
          SELECT 'D',133,123,16,124
UNION ALL SELECT 'N', 12,  3,15,  4
UNION ALL SELECT 'X',  2,  4, 5,  6
)
,
-- create a series of integers by using a side effect
-- of Vertica's TIMESERIES clause
-- a) limit: 0 to 3 - two timestamps, 3 microseconds apart
l(l) AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMPADD('MICROSECOND', 0,TIMESTAMP '1900-01-01')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMPADD('MICROSECOND', 3,TIMESTAMP '1900-01-01')
)
,
-- b) TIMESERIES on those two timestamps, with 1 microsecond as chosen spacing 
--    interval, then immediately extract the microsecond from the resulting timestamp
i(i) AS (
  SELECT
    MICROSECOND(ts)
  FROM l
  TIMESERIES ts AS '1 MICROSECOND' OVER(ORDER BY l)
)
-- start with verticalising - un-pivoting ..
SELECT
  shift
, i + 1 AS day_i -- the integer series is zero-based ...
, CASE i
    WHEN 0 THEN day01
    WHEN 1 THEN day02
    WHEN 2 THEN day03
    WHEN 3 THEN day04
    ELSE CAST(NULL AS INT)
  END AS val
FROM input CROSS JOIN i
;

The result is exactly the report above.
Another way to achieve it is to work with Vertica's EXPLODE() function. I only have to nest two queries because I want to start the day_i index with 1 and not 0, which is the behaviour of the function, hence position + 1:
WITH
-- some input data ...
input(Shift,day01,day02,day03,day04) AS (
          SELECT 'D',133,123,16,124
UNION ALL SELECT 'N', 12,  3,15,  4
UNION ALL SELECT 'X',  2,  4, 5,  6
)
,
explosion AS (
  SELECT 
    shift
  , EXPLODE(ARRAY[day01,day02,day03,day04]) OVER(PARTITION BY shift)
  FROM input
-- tst  shift | position | value 
-- tst -------+----------+-------
-- tst  D     |        0 |   133
-- tst  D     |        1 |   123
-- tst  D     |        2 |    16
-- tst  D     |        3 |   124
-- tst  [. . .]
)
SELECT
  shift
, position + 1 AS day_i
, value        AS val
FROM explosion
ORDER BY 1,2
;                                                                     ```




